# Unity InjectionFactory and Interceptors

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, unity-container, aop, ioc-container

I'm trying to use an exception interceptor along with an injectionfactory like this:

```
container.RegisterType<IProcessorService>(
    new HierarchicalLifetimeManager(),
    new InjectionFactory(c => processorFactory.CreateChannel()),
    new Interceptor<InterfaceInterceptor>(), 
    new InterceptionBehavior<AppExceptionInterceptor>());
```

Only problem is the interceptor is not working. The injection factory works but not the interceptor. For other types when I do interceptors without using an injection factory everything is fine and works.

Any ideas?

Cheers for any wisdom!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forgot to add the interception extension to the container!

```
container.AddNewExtension<Interception>();
```